# Google Cloud Platform | No Cloud Run Services shown on specific region when creating back-end network endpoint group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

On Google Cloud Platform, I'm trying to create a back-end service with a new serverless network endpoint group.

The region has to be very specific (europe-west3) and I already created multiple services on Cloud Run, including the one I want to use with this back-end.
I also created multiple back-ends before with the same set-up.

[Earlier created backends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp8Kj.png)

I've verified the regions of my services (all in europe-west3), yet when I create a new back-end service and add a new serverless network endpoint group, set the region to europe-west3 & Select Cloud Run as type, GCP shows "No Cloud Run services in current region".

[Service Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GTsh.png)

[No services when region is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K7QT.png)

Weirdest thing is, when I don't select a region, the list of services does show up. Once selected, it mentions "(undefined)" behind the service name.

[Services show when no region is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WudHY.png)

[Service "undefined"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzHMO.png)

Why can't I create a new back-end + network endpoint group and why could I do it before?
And how could I fix this?

This is my first question ever (on StackOverflow). Sorry for any bad etiquette!

Comment: It's a known issue by Google cloud, it will be fixed soon

Comment: IIRC you can use the CLI (gcloud) while the Console GUI is being updated.

Comment: This worked for me: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#gcloud_1

Comment: @JoshLubawy You should post that as an answer, worked for me too. Came in big, ty.

Answer (score 1):

Use the cloud shell in order to create the serverless NEG

```
gcloud compute network-endpoint-groups create <neg-name> \
  --region=<region name> \
  --network-endpoint-type=serverless \
  --cloud-run-service=<serviceName>
```

Comment: Your answer as written will not work. Make sure you copy and paste correctly.